# Deleting an object in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need some advise on the following problem:

I am using iOS Master Detail application template for my app, i encounter problem when i segue from master to details page.
My question is why `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` is triggered when segueing ?

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    List *list = nil;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

But in my situation i want to do the following i.e. when the user deletes object by swiping table cell from right i also delete object from server, this works well when there is single table view and there is no segueing. If i prevent `NSFetchResutlsController` form deleting object when i segue to details like below then after coming back from details view the table view cell do not respond to my click events. i.e. the table does not segue, nothing happens on clicking,

Can any one guide what is going wrong here ? How should i achieve this functionality properly ?

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            list = (List*)anObject;
            BOOL visible = [self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[RKGMasterViewController class]];

            if(list.listSyncStatus == [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] &&  visible) 
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self deleteDataFromServer:list];
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, first thing. The `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't delete anything. It doesn't do any updates to the data store at all. All it does it fetch objects and watch for changes.

It sounds like you are confusing the `tableview` delete row with deleting something from the data store.

You shouldn't really be changing the `NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate` methods to do anything more than updating the table.

However, when the user swipes the cell and taps `Delete` you should then be deleting the relevant data from the core data store on a background thread. You should also (as part of this process) send a request to delete the data from the server too.

If you do the deletion on a `background thread` (and background context) then the NSFRC will pick up the change and remove the cell from the table for you.

Comment: ok, what event of table view is triggered when user swipes table cell ?

Comment: When the user swipes the table view all that happens is a delete button appears. Nothing else. If the user taps the delete button then it runs a function in the tableViewDelegate called `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. It is here that you should be deleting the core data entity and sending a call to the server to delete the same object.

Comment: ok i have done what you said and half of my problem is solved. Now the remaining issue is when i tapped cell it segues to detail view and after coming back to master view the item is not there, because NSFetchResults Controller's didChangeObject method

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
line gets executed while segueing, how can i solve this ?

Comment: Can you show your code for the segue in your question. If you are not deleting the object then it should be OK.

Comment: Can you put it in your question please.

Comment: The Problem was resolved. it was a problem with RestKit Add fetch Request Block.